# Parsing text in Apps Script TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

Tags: google-apps-script, types

I'm using Apps Script in Google.  I get specifically-formatted emails, and I'm just trying to get the junk out.  I started using split to get rid of a bunch of junk before the first <.  Then I want to use another split based on > to get what I want.  But it gives me an error for the second split.  Any ideas?

```
var tmp,
  message = threads[i].getMessages()[0],
  oldsubject = message.getSubject(),
  content = message.getRawContent();
  theBody = message.getPlainBody();
  var fromstring = message.getFrom(); 
var partsArray = theBody.split('<');
var newBody = partsArray[1];
var testArray = newBody.split('>'); //TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
```

Comment: In your script, can you provide the sample value of `theBody` of `partsArray` for correctly replicating `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`? Because, in your script, I'm worried that `newBody` might be `undefined`. If my understanding is correct, how about `var testArray = newBody && newBody.split('>');`? But, in this case, when `newBody` is `undefined`, `testArray` is also `undefined` while no error occurs. I'm not sure whether this is your expected direction. I apologize for this.

Answer (score 0):

> var testArray = newBody.split('>');
> //TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

`newBody` is `undefined`. So, the engine cannot read property 'split' of `undefined`. Only `string`s have a `split` property.

Why is it `undefined`?

> var newBody = partsArray[1];

Because `partsArray` doesn't have two  elements. If `partsArray` is `[0]` instead of `[0,1]`, then it doesn't have a second element `[1]` to access.

Why doesn't `partsArray` have two elements?

> var partsArray = theBody.split('<');

Probably because there's no `<` in `theBody`.